# How can I add a bash alias to .bashrc which will accept an argument?

Tags: linux, bash, alias

I'm new to Linux but want to experiment with aliases.

I have a directory of branches of our software release. The directory structure looks like this:

```
/home/username/software/release-1
/home/username/software/release-2
/home/username/software/release-3 etc
```

I'd like to add an alias so I could type something like "cdr 1" and automatically cd into the release-1 directory.

I know I could add these lines to my .bashrc:

```
alias cdr 1='cs /home/username/software/release-1'
alias cdr 2='cs /home/username/software/release-2' etc
```

but is there some way to pass an argument into the alias so I don't have to update it for every new release?

thanks
Matt

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can put them in a function

```
cdr(){
  to=$1
  cd /home/username/software/release-${to}
}
```

to use,

```
...
cdr 1
cdr 2
...
```

Comment: +1, AFAIK you can't do what author wants with aliases, while functions is a very flexible mechanism with no drawbacks compared to aliases. And you can also use _getopt_ inside such function to make the "alias" handy for real.

Comment: Used that several times myself. For example an improved `ducks` (disk usage, top space hogs) from the Linux Server Hacks books.